# What happened to the Meta link?

Tags: support, meta

We used to be able to reach *this* meta site from the StackExchange logo which had a drop-down. Not I could not find and but luckily guessed the right URL to ask *this* question:

Where is the link to travel.meta.stackexchange.com now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It got moved in the redesign.

The StackExchange logo on the left side of the menu used to be a drop-down menu showing all your sites. Now it's just a link to the StackExchange homepage.

The drop-down menu moved to the far right side of the menu bar now. Click it, and it will show you the "current community" and its corresponding meta site.

[image: screenshot of the far-right menu]